# How to disable remote debugging of android app

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

I have a hybrid android application and i want to remove the remote debugging option to hide my application functionality when the user attaches USB cable and starts to debug in a chrome dev tool. I have properly signed the apk and release it but still that I can see that application is showing and available to chrome inspect. Is there any solution to hide this feature?

Comment: can you share the command you use to build the prod env. By default when you build cordova release with signed, the debugging console should be removed

Comment: Yes, this is true but strange not working in my case. I am building the artifact through "gradle clean build" command. It will create both the release and debug version of apks.

Comment: i never use "gradle clean build" before. Can you try using "cordova build android --release --buildConfig=path" where path is the place you put your build.json signature file. It works when i use that

Comment: Actually I am using Cordova as a library inside of my android application and this Cordova library was built as a release mode. So I don't understand how it should work to generate an apk.